# Create a deep (horizontal) object in a loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, for-loop

I wasn't sure what the best way to word this question is but basically I'm looking to create a  loop that create objects like this:

```
var dictionary = {};
var arr = [
              ["for", "item", "in", "list"],
              ["if", "condition"]
          ];

// Insert Magic Loop to yield:

dictionary.for.item.in.list // {} (exists, as well as rest of chain)
dictionary.if.condition     // {} (exists, as well as rest of chain)
dictionary.for.item         // {}
dictionary.test             // undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
function create(arrArray) {
   for(var i = 0; i < arrArray.length; i++) {
       var arr = arrArray[i];

       var _dict = dictionary;

       for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
           if(!_dict[arr[j]]) {
              _dict[arr[j]] = {};
           }
           _dict = _dict[arr[j]];
       } 
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a subset of the solution. I wrote a function that takes in an array and a dictionary as parameters:

```
function create(arr, dict) {           
    var _dict = dict;

    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if(!_dict[arr[j]]) {
           _dict[arr[j]] = {};
        }
        _dict = _dict[arr[j]];
    } 
}

var dictionary = {};

create(["for", "item", "in", "list"], dictionary);
create(["if", "condition"], dictionary)
```

If you're not worried about overwriting, you can take out the `if` in the loop:

```
function create(arr, dict) {           
    var _dict = dict;

    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        _dict[arr[j]] = {};
        _dict = _dict[arr[j]];
    } 
}
```

And for better readability:

```
function create(arr, dict) {           
    var _dict = dict;

    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        var key = arr[j];
        _dict[key] = {};
        _dict = _dict[key];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Dang - thanks a lot! This looks great. I just tested this out - Diggin' the one with the if statement. This is exactly what I was looking for - Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
var dictionary = {};
var arr = [
              ["for", "item", "in", "list"],
              ["if", "condition"]
          ];
for(var i in arr){
    var _i = arr[i];
    var x = dictionary;
    for(var ii in _i){
        x[_i[ii]] = {};
        x = x[_i[ii]];
    }
}
console.log(dictionary);
console.log(dictionary.for.item.in.list);
console.log(dictionary.if.condition );
console.log(dictionary.for.item);
console.log(dictionary.test );
```

Answer (score 2):

This will need some modification (restart at top for each sequence), but shows the general idea of descending-down:

```
var arr = ["foo", "if", "then", "bar"]
var dictionary = {}
var obj = dictionary // keep original
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   var key = arr[i]
   // assign and "move to next".
   // this could be done as `obj = obj[key] = {}`
   obj[key] = {}
   obj = obj[key]
}
```

Happy coding

Comment: One question regarding this solution. How does dictionary end up with everything? It looks like object is referencing dictionary, but doesn't object get overwritten each iteration?

Comment: @Matt yep, it will get overwritten. You just need to adapt pst's solution and make it similar to mine. i.e., wrap it in a function that accepts the dictionary as an argument.

Comment: Hmm. Well his solution works too, I tested it haha. I just don't understand why..

Comment: @Matt Assignment does *not* make a copy of an object. In this case the top object is always the `{}` initially assigned to `dictionary`. (Each level is a new `{}` created below) and each `obj[key]` *modifies* the current object referred to in the `obj` variable (the object referred to by `obj` changes).

Answer (score 2):

```
var dictionary = {},
    arr = [
          ["for", "item", "in", "list"],
          ["if", "condition"]
    ];

// loop the outer array
for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    var current = dictionary, // set "current" to the top-level object (dictionary)
        sub = arr[x];     // reference to sub-item

    // loop sub-list
    for (var y = 0; y < sub.length; y++) {
        // create the new object on the "current" object,
        // then assign that new object to be "current"
        current = current[sub[y]] = {};
    }
}

console.log(dictionary);
```